# How to make preg_replace not hungry?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string:

```
$str = '{:de}Hallo Welt{:}{:en}Helo world{:}';
```

now i need to get substring for setted language.

```
$placeholder = '{:en}';
$lang_content =  preg_replace('/(.*)'.preg_quote($placeholder).'(.*)'.preg_quote('{:}').'(.*)/sm', '\2', $str);
```

in case of value for placeholder `{:en}` i get `Helo world` as value for `$lang_content`, it works fine, but in case `{:de}` i get `Hallo Welt{:}{:en}Helo world`. 
How can it be fixed? thanx!

Comment: It's called `lazy` in regex language. `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the regex lazy by adding a `?` in the second capture.

```
$str = '{:de}Hallo Welt{:}{:en}Helo world{:}';

$placeholder = '{:de}';
$lang_content =  preg_replace('/(.*)'.preg_quote($placeholder).'(.*?)'.preg_quote('{:}').'(.*)/sm', '\2', $str);

echo $lang_content; // Hallo Welt
```

https://3v4l.org/m6AGF

---

An optional method would be to use preg_match to get an associative array.

```
$str = '{:de}Hallo Welt{:}{:en}Helo world{:}';

preg_match_all("/\{:(.*?)}(.*?)\{/", $str, $matches);
$matches = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

var_dump($matches);
echo $matches["de"]; // Hallo Welt
```

https://3v4l.org/ELB2B

Comment: Thanx  a lot! It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ungreedy flag (`U`).

You can update the flags at the end of your regex from `/sm` to `/smU` for the result to stop at the next occurrence of `{:}` in the string and not at the last one.

If the string is to contain several occurrences, maybe you can also add the global (`g`) flag so the regex doesn't stop after the first one.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/4XSPoz/3

By the way, it seems that your are using preg_replace as a way to find a substring and don't actually need to replace it in the result, maybe you should use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.